# How to await for connection before resolving other Promises?

Tags: javascript, promise

I found interesting problem (not a real task):

```
class Client {
  async connect() {
      return new Promise(resolve => {
          setTimeout(() => {
              console.log('connect');
              resolve()
          }, 2000);
      })
  }

  async request() {
      console.log('done something')
  }
}

class Api {
  #client;

  async getClient() {
      if (!this.#client) {
          const client = new Client();
          await client.connect();
          this.#client = client;
      }
      return this.#client;
  }

  async request() {
      const client = await this.getClient();
      return client.request();
  }
}

const run = async () => {
  const api = new Api();

  await Promise.all([api.request(), api.request(), api.request(), api.request()]);
}

run();
```

It will output this:

```
connect
request completed
connect
request completed
connect
request completed
connect
request completed
```

Obviously, we need to wait for initial connection and then resolve other requests, so output would be like this:

```
connect
request completed
request completed
request completed
request completed
```

My working solution:

```
class Client {
    async connect() {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                console.log('connect');
                resolve()
            }, 2000);
        })
    }

    async request() {
        console.log('request completed')
    }
}

class Api {
    #connecting = false;
    #client;
    #queue = [];

    async getClient() {
        if (!this.#client && !this.#connecting) {
            this.#connecting = true;
            const client = new Client();
            await client.connect();

            this.#connecting = false;
            this.#client = client;

            this.resolveQueue(client)
        }
        return this.#client;
    }

    async resolveQueue(client) {
        await Promise.all(this.#queue.map(task => task(client)))
    }

    async request() {
        const client = await this.getClient();

        if (client) {
            return client.request();       
        } else {
            this.#queue.push(async (client) => client.request());
        }

    }
}

const run = async () => {
    const api = new Api();

    await Promise.all([api.request(), api.request(), api.request(), api.request()]);
}

run();
```

But it seems there should be more clear/easy way to do this, because I added a lot of layers and complexity. Also, I think the goal here is to add as little changes as possible, keeping the code structure as is, which I also tried to achieve. In real world situation, I would probably rewrite this completely and made it more verbose.

Answer (score 2):

There are various different approaches to this. With minimal changes to your code, there are two things you'll want to do:

1. Remember a promise in `Client` for the `connect` result, so you can wait for it to be fulfilled in `request`
2. In `Api`, set `this.#client` **immediately**, before awaiting the connection result, so that multiple calls to `request` don't create multiple separate `Client` instances

```js
class Client {
    // Have a promise for connection, which also gives you a handy way
    // to know that `connect` has been called
    connectionPromise = null;
    async connect() {
        // Remember the connection promise
        this.connectionPromise = new Promise((resolve) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                console.log("connect");
                resolve();
            }, 200);
        });
        return this.connectionPromise;
    }

    async request() {
        // Check that `connect` has been called
        if (!this.connectionPromise) {
            throw new Error(`Can't call 'request' before calling 'connect'`);
        }
        // Wait until the promise is fulfilled
        await this.connectionPromise;
        // Now do the request
        console.log("done something");
    }
}

class Api {
    #client;

    async getClient() {
        if (!this.#client) {
            // Set `this.#client` immediately, before awaiting
            // the connection, so multiple overlapping calls to
            // `request` use the **same** client
            this.#client = new Client();
            await this.#client.connect();
        }
        return this.#client;
    }

    async request() {
        const client = await this.getClient();
        return client.request();
    }
}

const run = async () => {
    const api = new Api();

    await Promise.all([api.request(), api.request(), api.request(), api.request()]);
};

run();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

**But**, I'd suggest you separate `Client` into two parts:

- The part that does connection (which can just be a function; if you wanted, it *could* be a `static` method on `Client`)
- The client object that can do requests

That way, you never have a stateful `Client` instance that isn't ready for use. By the time you get one (from the function that does connection), it's connected and good to go.

Comment: Wow, this is amazing, thank you! If you could provide different approach (just for perspective), it would be really great :) Also, I could use a little roast of my code (I know I know SO isn't the best place for this, but I think this could be very beneficial)

Comment: Oh, sorry, didn't notice your suggestions. Will keep it in mind!